# Is it possible to insert two subsequent newlines in an arXiv abstract?

Tags: arxiv

Is it possible to insert two subsequent newlines in an arXiv abstract? For example, in the abstract of https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475 I would have preferred to have 2 newlines instead of just one newline between the section of the abstract, as shown below:

```
Objective: Patient notes in electronic health records (EHRs) […]

Materials and Methods: We introduce the first […]

Results: Our ANN model outperforms […]

Conclusion: Our findings support the use […]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have emailed the arXiv technical support and the answer is no, it is not possible to insert two subsequent newlines in an arXiv abstract.